# IP address of the SMTP GMAIL

Tags: windows, gmail, smtp

would you know what is the IP address of the SMTP GMAIL
(It allows you to send mail from a batch windows)

```
@echo off

set repertoire="C:\Mon repertoire\"
set emetteur=email.emmeteur@domaine.com
set eMail=email.destinataireg@domaine.com
set copie=-cc destinataire.copie@domaine.com
set subj=-s "Titre de mon message"
set server=-server smtp.domaine.com
set x=-x "X-Header-Test: header supplémentaire optionnel inséré dans le mail"
set debug=-debug -log envois-mails.log -timestamp

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i IN ('DIR /B /O-D %repertoire%*.log') DO set fichier="%repertoire:"=%%%i" && GOTO DONE || GOTO DONE
: DONE

blat %fichier% -mime -8bitmime -to %eMail% %copie% -f %emetteur% %subj% %server% %debug% %x%
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Rather than IP address you should actually use domain address since IP address might easily change.

For smtp server in google domain use `smtp.gmail.com` and port `587`.

Some details on the topic can be found [here](http://support.qualityunit.com/107274-How-to-configure-Gmail-SMTP-settings-).

---

On a side note - IMHO it's **really a shameful thing** to do to come to superuser.com and ask question before reviewing at least **top 3 pages on a google search** for `gmail smtp settings` which I'm 100% sure you did not do.

Comment: I tried it but I still have a problem ! here is the error:
2014.07.21 11:15:16 (Mon): The SMTP server does not like the sender name.
    Have you set your mail address correctly?

Comment: please include the error in your original question. Although i do not see an option in your batch code to enable TLS authentication which might be the cause of an error you are receiving.

Comment: @user2480100 Heres is the problem description the same as yours: https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/blat/conversations/topics/7729 and the solution: "You need stunnel to provide the Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) as required by
GMail. See the line above that says STARTTLS, and the next line that
identifies ports 465 or 587. Blat does not support SSL itself, but it can
send messages through another program which does provide SSL."

Comment: So what do I need to change or add to my script?

Comment: Nothing. Your script is complete as it is capable of sending emails via SMTP. It's just not able to send emails via Gmail SMTP server as it does not include SSL/TLS authentication. You need some other program that will handle secure connection after which this script of yours would be able to send emails through SSL tunnel that will be established. That's is completely different question.

Comment: ok thank you, 
In fact I just changed my SMTP to that provider my internet connection, and normally I should be able to send mail to any address except that it not accept gmail addresses